# How to query number of items from two tables?

Tags: android, sqlite

My database has a Manifest table and an Item table which Manifest can have 1 to many Item but 1 Item can only has 1 Manifest. The tables' structure is as below:

**Manifest Table**

```
ID    Name
1     Bill_1
2     Bill_2
```

**Item Table**

```
ID    Name    Manifest_ID (FK)
1     Item_1  1
2     Item_2  1
3     Item_3  2
```

What is the query so that I could get the following result?

**Query Result**

```
Manifest_ID    Manifest_Name    Number of Item
1              Bill_1           2
2              Bill_2           1
```

Comment: Search for `INNER JOIN` and `COUNT`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inner join and group by:

```
SELECT  Manifest.ID, Manifest.Name, count(Manifest_ID)
    FROM Manifest INNER JOIN Item ON Manifest.ID = Item.Manifest_ID
    group by Manifest_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the tips gave by @Matt Raines. I have successfully solved this with the following query:

```
SELECT m._id, m.name, COUNT(i._id) AS 'Number of Item' FROM Manifest m 
LEFT JOIN Item i ON m._id = i.manifest_id 
GROUP BY m._id
```